# The difference between connectedness and path-connectedness intuitively

Tags: general-topology, intuition

The difference of connectedness and path-connectedness quite bothers me. I know the counterexample. Connectedness expresses the sense that the set can't be separated into two sets "nonrelevant", path-connectedness express the sense that all points in the set can be linked, but what I couldn't see what's the difference intuitively.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of intuition you're looking for. There are much more pathological examples of connected spaces than the topologist's sine curve - for example, there are countable connected Hausdorff topological spaces. I suspect typical counterexamples embedded in Euclidean space consist of path-connected components that get very close to each other.

Comment: Path connectedness is a much more strigent condition. To be path connected, first the space has to be able to suport more than trivial 1-point paths. This means it has to have subsets that look something like intervals on the real numbers. This puts many additional conditions on the topology. By comparison, a connected space doesn't even have to be . The various examples that Dustan mentions were chosen not just to demonstrate that path-connected and connected are different. But to show that they remain different even when the space fully supports curves,